# Trigger run after hibernate insert returning error

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have two tables: `td` and `last_td`. I wrote this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_find_last_td()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    delete from last_td;

    insert into last_td
        select
            t1.name,
            t1.max,
            t2.due_date,
            t2.fixed_rate,
            t2.unit_price,
            t2.reading_time
        from (select
                t2.name,
                max(t2.reading_date)
                from td t2
                where
                t2.reading_date > now() 
                group by t2.name) t1,
                td t2
        where
            t1.name = t2.name
            and t1.max = t2.reading_date;
    commit;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

to be used as a trigger as below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_find_last_td
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON td
EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_find_last_td();
```

I have a Java application running on Wildfly 10.1.0.Final with hibernate 5.0.10.Final using `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>`

But now every time hibernate tries to insert data into `td` it outputs this error:

```
 Hint: Use a BEGIN block with an EXCEPTION clause instead.
 Where: PL/pgSQL function f_find_last_td() line 25 at SQL statement
 14:21:00,425 INFO [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (EJB default - 9) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

Of course I could add `EXCEPTION` to catch that, but why exacly I'm receiving this error?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you insert from postgres instead from the java app?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that

Comment: Remove `commit` and it'll works

Comment: `t2.reading_date > now()`: after every insert on `td` I must only select rows that have max date and unique name, besides the fact their date should be after `now()`. These rows must be exacltly the same as on `td` and `last_td` for my java app to work as planned. I don't see how update could improve any boilerplate code.

Comment: You are storing a single row each time trigger is fired. Deleting the whole table content requires time, then a new insert, you can get same result by updating a single record.

Comment: @McNets It worked! But why? If you're considering explaining put that on an answer, please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702678/3270427